# node-sass: Fontawesome icon encoding issues

Tags: css, encoding

I'm using `node-sass` and `gulp-sass` to compile my assets.

Now when I'm running gulp with sass `outputStyle: 'nested'` (default), the fontawesome characters are changed from:

```
$fa-var-home: "\f015";
```

to

```
.fa-home:before {
  content: "";
}
```

Using this in the browser seems to be working fine.

When running sass with `outputStyle: 'compressed'`, I'm getting different characters:

```
.fa-home:before{content:"ï€•"}
```

Now the strange part: sometimes, but I don't have any steps to reproduce this, the characters are also shown just like that, so `ï€•` instead of a home icon.

I can't put my fingers on it and in 99.99% of the cases it is just fine. But in some situations it goes wrong and I don't understand why!

Answer (score 1):

recently I had the same situation. 
whenever you compile  compiling using compressed outputStyle it's also removing charset: utf-8. For that reason you are getting that different characters.

So I'm using [postcss-normalize-charset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-normalize-charset) which basically add necessary charset keeping outputStyle compressed